# Intent equivalent in WP7

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, android-intent

Is there any equivalent concept in WP7 as Android Intents?

Basically, I want to use my application to interact with another application (if installed on the device).

Thanks
Souvik

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible...

Comment: since when windows implements useful features? XD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each application runs in a sandbox, it is not possible to interact with another application.
To interact with native applications, there are the [Launchers and Choosers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769556%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

**Launchers and Choosers**

[Windows Phone 7 Launchers & Choosers: The absolute guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136166/Windows-Phone-7-Launchers-Choosers-The-absolute-gu)

[Launchers and Choosers Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)